# Android - Force Activity to show first whenever user comes back from background

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.android

I am developing an app that need password when app first launch or come back from background to foreground. First launch is easy. But when app back to foreground from background, it shows my main page for a second and then my password screen comes up. I don't need that at all for security reasons.

And If I put my password activity as launcher activity, my flow for the rest of my application starts from the first page(which contains 12-15 fragments).

For example,
password activity => Main activity -> Fragment A -> Fragment B -> Fragment C => app goes in background and comes again => password activity => Main activity -> Fragment A

It should stay on Fragment C. For that I created dialog style popover for password activity.

```
<style name="dialog_light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
   <item name="@android:windowBackground">@color/whitegrey</item>
   <item name="@android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   <item name="@android:textColor">@color/black</item>        
</style>
```

and call it from the main activity whenever i need that and finish it after password entered. but by doing this, the main activity is displayed for a sec(in some device for fraction of sec) but I don't need that.

Sorry for not putting my code here because I am not at my working place.

Thank you :)

Comment: did you try put open dialog in onResume()

Comment: @androidAhmed Thanks for comment. Do you mean by open my password activity in OnResume of my main activity ? I don't do that. but i will surely try this.

Comment: yes you can try onResume() or in onStart()

Comment: ok. thanks. will it open my password activity first than my MainActivity ?

Answer (score 0):

The only  answer I can think of is to create an abstract base fragment and base activity in your application to which all other fragments and activities will be linked as children and then in onResume() and in onStart() of both your Base Activity and Base Fragment you can trigger the Intent for password activity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. can you pls give me samaple code for what you say ? It will be helpful.

Comment: Can You share your code?

With that actually, I will be able to help you more